# Variable inside array call results in bad substitution

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I'm trying to access data from an array while in a loop.

this command works fine..

```
echo "text: ${hnr1[1]}"
```

and this:

```
echo "text: ${hnr1[$loopnr]}"
```

However, this is giving me an headache;

```
echo "text: ${hnr$loopnr[1]}"
```

will result in:

```
**: text: ${hnr$loopnr[1]}: bad substitution**
```

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Edit:
Don't get to hung up on the loop, it was a way for me to test stuff..
The data is:

```
array **hnr1** has **20** entries regarding **map 1**
array **hnr2** has **20** entries regarding **map 2**
```

so my optimal function would be:

```
' data=${hnr$mapnr[$field]} '
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `echo "text: ${hnr$loopnr[1]}"`? “Access data” _how_? What format is the data in?

Comment: the data is in an array called hnr1 --> hnr66 the data is string / integer

Comment: Is that an array, or are these 66 separate variables? Arrays are (often) declared like `hnr=(value1 value2 …)` in bash.

Comment: hnr1 contains 20 values regarding map1, hnr2 contains 20 values of map2 and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use an associative array instead of 66 different array variables. You can borrow a page from `awk` and use a delimiter that won't show up in the keys to emulate multi-dimensional arrays:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A hnr
hnr[1,0]=foo
hnr[1,1]=bar
#...
hnr[66,0]=cat
hnr[66,1]=dog
# Or all at once declare -A nhr=([1,0]=foo ... [66,1]=dog)

loopnr=66
echo "Text: ${hnr[$loopnr,1]}"
```

You could also use `bash`'s [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), but the above way is going to be a lot simpler and easier to understand:

```sh
declare -a hnr66=(ball bat)
loopnr=66
# Build up the variable name - note the array index has to be part of this
varname="hnr$loopnr[1]"
# And use it.
echo "Text: ${!varname}"
```

Comment: now I already have the data as: hnr1 contains 20 values regarding map1, hnr2 contains 20 values of map2 and so on.. there must be some logic way to access via ${hnr$loopnr[1]}  (or something that works?)

Comment: @JoBe You would of course rewrite the rest of your code to match using an associate array to store everything.

Comment: I'm pretty new at arrays, but that looks pretty simple, would... echo "Text: ${hnr[$loopnr,$val]}" also work?

Comment: @JoBe: see the 2nd half of Shawn's answer where he shows you how to use `indirect expansion` to access the values in your current arrays ... net result is it's doable but a bit convoluted; as for your 2nd comment/question re: `echo "Text ..."` ... "When in doubt, try it out!"